# Loop through array function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple slider that loops through an array and updates the text in certain elements on my page, I have the following but im unsure on what the best way is to look through my array?

http://jsfiddle.net/g6wvuwb3/1/

```
var people = [
    ['image-1.jpg', 'Thomas', 'All about thomas'],
    ['image-2.jpg', 'Jamie', 'All about Jamie'],
    ['image-3.jpg', 'Kendrick ', 'All about kendrick']
];

setInterval(function () {
    $('.quote').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.diverse-people').velocity({
        'margin-left': -$(this).width()
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', people[0][0]);
        $('.diverse-people').velocity({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, 1000);
        $('.quote h6').text(people[0][1]);
        $('.quote p').text(people[0][2]);
        $('.quote').fadeIn(1000);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Where you want the array to iterate?

Answer (score 0):

To loop through your array you would do this:

```
var people = [
    ['image-1.jpg', 'Thomas', 'All about thomas'],
    ['image-2.jpg', 'Jamie', 'All about Jamie'],
    ['image-3.jpg', 'Kendrick ', 'All about kendrick']
];

for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    console.log(people[i][1]);
}
```

Not totally sure what you're asking, but hopefully this answers it.

Edit:

To access array elements use this:

```
people[0][1]
```

Changing 0 and 1 for the keys you need.

Comment: what's the point of using `for..in` if you're using an index anyway? and what's worse, the index is out of scope of the iteration. Just use regular `for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++)` loop.

Comment: @lascort changes made

Answer (score 0):

This way you can iterate in the array.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(people, function(el){

      console.log(el[0]);
      console.log(el[1]);
      console.log(el[2]); 

});
```

Other way (If you want to use it many a times.)

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(people, function(el){

          console.log(el[0]);
          console.log(el[1]);
          console.log(el[2]); 

    });
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why prototype? isn't it easier to just call `people.forEach()`? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Actually i use it this way, Because if `people` would be an `object` with properties then `people.forEach()` won't work. But `Array.prototype.forEach.call(people, function(el){
});` will work.